# как исправить ошибку в Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

В Python:

[image: в python]

При запуске через терминал так выходит:

[image: при запуске через терминал так выходит]

Я создаю бота для доставки, у меня выходят такие ошибки. Что мне надо изменить, чтобы бот запустился. Я пробовал изменить, но ошибка все таки так и осталась.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Doniyor Klichev\Desktop\DeliveryBot-master\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import  Telebot, types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Telebot'

C:\Users\Doniyor Klichev\Desktop\DeliveryBot-master>

Answer (score 2):

Вам же прямо написали, что модуль telebot не установлен. Установите его с помощью pip.

pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

PS. Так я походу понял. Вы криво инициализируете телебот вот здесь

```
bot = Telebot(config=token)
```

Вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр класса Telebot, но по факту на данный момент у вас нету класса Telebot, однако есть telebot. Все что нужно сделать это

```
bot = telebot.Telebot(config=token)
```

PSS. И на будущее, пожалуйста присылайте не скриншоты а код в текстовом виде.

Comment: у меня есть pyTelegramBotApi и даже telebot но всё такие проблема не изменился

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Doniyor Klichev\Desktop\DeliveryBot-master\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import  Telebot, types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Telebot'

C:\Users\Doniyor Klichev\Desktop\DeliveryBot-master>

Comment: @Legion гляньте ответ ещё раз